# Is self-hosted gitlab able to use gitpod?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, gitpod

I host gitlab on GKE, following https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-gke-gitlab.

- chart version gitlab-4.2.4
- gitlab app version 13.2.4
  Now, on gitlab page, I tried to use gitpod instead of default Web IDE.

gitlab document https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/gitpod.html says there is setting on `Admin Area > Settings > General` but looks not exist
[image]

So I wonder if we can use gitpod on self-hosted gitlab.

I appreciate it if someone would give some info

Answer (score 1):

It's just because of version of the gitlab.
With gitlab 13.7.0, gitpod option appeared on Setting